# Extracting hyperlinks from an RSS feed with Yahoo Pipes

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I would like to filter the descriptions from a webcomic RSS feed and extract all links with a specific link text, using Yahoo Pipes. For example, for the text "This chapter began here" and a description containing the following:

```
<a href="http://example.com/1234.html">This chapter began here</a>.
<a href="http://cuteoverload.com/">Here are some great kitten pictures</a>
```

I would want the output to be

```
http://example.com/1234.html
```

My best guess is that this will involve a regex, but after 45 minutes of research I'm not really sure where to begin. I'm not seeing how to use a regex to extract text rather than just replacing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex  should do the trick.

**A) The "Replace" argument**

```
(.*<a href=")(http://example\.com/[^"]*)(.*)
```

to cut the description in 3 parts

```
(.*<a href=")
(http://example\.com/[^"]*)
(.*)
```

**B)  The "With" argument** to replace the whole description with the second part

```
$2
```